# Backend Image uploader not working

Tags: magento2, backend, uploader

The upload image function recently broke on my backend, and I have no idea what may have caused it. This product already has a photo. I can click to add a photo, select the photo, but it never actually shows up on this page, or updates the product. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

EDIT: I'm still having this issue. Turns out it returned after compiling again. It's not related to extensions as I originally had thought. Any ideas? I'm now up to 2.2.7 with the same issue.

Comment: This appears to be the same issue as:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8337
However I was not able to fix anything using the locale settings.

Comment: I'm still having this issue. Turns out it returned after compiling again. It's not related to extensions as I originally had thought. Any ideas? I'm now up to 2.2.7 with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove cache folders and run :

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
chmod 777 -R .
```

Also Refer this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904859/product-thumbnail-images-are-not-displayed-in-backend-after-manual-upload-in-mag

Comment: I just did the chmod 777 -R and now I'm getting a 500 error on every page

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was an extension earlier causing this, but now found out a permanent fix for my issue is by disabling the module: Magento_ProductVideo.